# MVC 6 Tag Helpers for dynamic check box list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, tag-helpers

I am writing a survey application in ASP.NET Core and allow the user to select the format of the answers to there questions. Radiobutton, Checkbox and dropdown.

I store the available options in an IEnumerable

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }
```

When selecting with a drop down i can use the asp-for and asp-items.

```
<select asp-items="Model.Options" asp-for="PollAnswer"></select>
```

When working with checkbox's i don't have the asp-items helper.

So i need the checkbox to pass PollAnswer the value of the checked checkbox's.

Something like

```
@foreach (var o in Model.Options)
{
    <input asp-for="PollAnswer" value="@o.Value"/>@o.Value <br/>
}
```

If there is a way to do this in Razor that would be fine too.